# Cheerio does not come with all selector

Tags: javascript, jquery, cheerio

While jQuery comes with a very useful all-selector http://api.jquery.com/all-selector/
What I want to do is find selectors that contains css position absolute, this can be easily archived by doing:

```
$('*').filter(function(){
  return $(this).css('position') == "absolute";
});
```

so the question is there a similar solution for cheerio?

Comment: Why in the world would you not do `$(".test")` to start?

Comment: yes i can use $('test'), but how about if i want to filter $(this).css('position') == "absoute" for example...

Comment: An example that makes MORE sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The asterisk works fine, try it like this

```
var html  = '<div class="test" style="position:absolute">test</div>';
    html += '<div class="test" style="position:relative">test2</div>';

var $ = cheerio.load(html);

var elems = $('*').filter(function(){
                return $(this).css('position') == "absolute";
            });

console.log( elems.html() ); // returns just "test"
```

note that you have to return the result, Cheerio is not jQuery, and there is no DOM, so any modification has to be returned to a new variable.

Comment: There is a DOM, it's just stored within `$` after loading `html`, and selections need to be retrieved from there.

Comment: (Then again I guess it depends on how the reader defines "DOM"...)

Comment: @BoltClock - there is of course a document and a model, so there is a DOM of sorts, but not like in the browser. I think Cheerio constructs something similar with a HTML parser, using a lot of regular expressions and array methods, as it doesn't have access to a browsers HTML parser.

Answer (score 0):

```
$(".test").each(function(){
   //You will get all elements contains test class
});
```